# Как изменить язык контента якорем

Tags: jquery, css

```js
$(function() {  
    var jGroup = $('.group'),
        jContent = $('.content'); 
    jGroup.on('click', function(event) {
      var jThis = $(event.currentTarget);
      jGroup.removeClass('opened');
      jContent.find('.container').removeClass('opened');
      jThis.addClass('opened'); 
      if (jThis.hasClass('a')) {
        jContent.find('.container.a').addClass('opened');
        jContent.find('.group.ru').addClass('linkid'); 
        jContent.find('.group.en').removeClass('linkid');
      };
      if (jThis.hasClass('b')) {
        jContent.find('.container.b').addClass('opened');
        jContent.find('.group.en').addClass('linkid');
        jContent.find('.group.ru').removeClass('linkid');
      }
  });
});
```

```css
.container { display: none; }
.linkid { font-weight: 600; }    
.container.opened { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="content">


<div id='header'>
  <div id="share" class="groups-container">
    <a href="#" class="group ru a">RU</a>
    <a href="#" class="group linkid en b">// EN</a> 
  </div>

 <!-- RU -->
  <div id='buttons' class="container a">
    <div id='button'><a class="projects" href="/projects#ru">Проекты</a>    </div>
    <div id='button'><a class="scrapbook" href="/scrapbook#ru" >Альбом</a></div>
    <div id='button'><a class="about" href="/about#ru">О нас</a></div>
    <div id='button'><a class="contact" href="/contact#ru">Контакты</a></div>
  </div>

    <!-- EN -->
  <div id='buttons' class="container opened b">
      <div id='button'><a class="projects" href="/projects-ru#en">Projects</a></div>
      <div id='button'><a class="scrapbook" href="/scrapbook#en" >Scrapbook</a></div>
      <div id='button'><a class="about" href="/about#en">About</a></div>
      <div id='button'><a class="contact" href="/contact#en">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Так а в чём суть вопроса? )

Comment: Хочу чтобы при переходе по ссылке /projects-ru#en включалось правило для container.b, а при переходе по ссылке /projects-ru#ru - правило для container.a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй вот таким образом

```
var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
if(hash == 'en'){
   jContent.find('.container.b').addClass('opened');
   jContent.find('.group.en').addClass('linkid');
   jContent.find('.group.ru').removeClass('linkid');
}else if(hash == 'ru'){
   jContent.find('.container.a').addClass('opened');
   jContent.find('.group.ru').addClass('linkid'); 
   jContent.find('.group.en').removeClass('linkid');
};
```

Comment: А куда его надо поставить, а то не работает?

Comment: @Виктор, нужно этот код запускать вместе с страницей. Если `Jquery`, то в `$(function() {...});`. А если вы хотите, что бы он работал при клике на ссылку, то он не будет работать. Так как когда кликаешь на ссылку с hash тегом одним, страница не перезапускается

Comment: Спасибо большое, получилось.